# How to override gradle settings using a local file?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to override some properties from my root gradle file. Those properties are in the ext block in the root gradle file for my project. I do not want to change those properties in the project files as it could generate problems when making a commit and push to the repository because i want some values that only i will use.

I already override some properties in the gradle.properties file by creating my own gradle.properties in my local .gradle folder. Can I do the same with the ext block in the gradle file?

Comment: Think you'd have to change the ext block to first look up if those properties are already set, and use that value if so